# Get the ylim from a barplot in order to use it in another function

Tags: r, plot

I have two barplots being plotted, where one is stacked and the other isn't.

```
b <- barplot(c(10,20,30,40), beside=T)
c <- barplot(t(cbind(c(1,2,3,4), c(3,4,2,1))), beside=F)
```

I would like the stacked barplot to have the same `ylim` as the first. Appreciate any advice.

Comment: Get the `ylim` from the merged data before plotting, and assign it when plotting `ylim=myY_limits`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the `ylim` of the first plot after you've plotted it with `par("usr")` and use it for the second plot:

```
# plot the first barplot
b <- barplot(c(10,20,30,40), beside=T)
# get the extreme coordinates for y axis
ylim_plot1 <- par("usr")[3:4]
# plot the second barplot with parameter ylim
c <- barplot(t(cbind(c(1,2,3,4), c(3,4,2,1))), beside=F, ylim=ylim_plot1)
```